# How to add a default ViewController along with the navigation drawer ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have implemented a `menuViewVontroller` for navigation drawer that works fine. I am able to render the view controllers on their respective menu buttons. I have one ViewController that loads up first and then I display other view controllers from the navigation menu i.e. Home menu displays the `homeViewVontroller` etc. as you can see in the screen shots.

[image]
[image]

But I also want my app to show the `homeControllerView` when the viewController loads. It is currently rendering an empty screen as the view controller is empty. When I write the below code in `viewDidLoad()` method, I am not getting the navigation drawer, just the homeViewController gets displayed (as shown in the picture below).

[image]

```
let view = UIView()
    let controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SliderController")
    addChild(controller)
    view.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.view.addSubview(controller.view)
    self.topView = view
```

What can I do to render both the `homeViewController` and the `menuViewController` in the same screen.

EDIT: My code when the user presses the menu item

```
@IBAction func didTapMenuButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    guard let menuViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuViewController") as? MenuViewController else { return }
    menuViewController.didTapMenuType = {
        menuType in
        self.transitionToNew(menuType)
    }
    menuViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    menuViewController.transitioningDelegate = self
    present(menuViewController, animated: true)
}
func transitionToNew(_ menuType: MenuType) {
    let title = String(describing: menuType).capitalized
    self.title = title

    topView?.removeFromSuperview()
    switch menuType {


    case .promotion:
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .yellow
        view.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.addSubview(view)
        self.topView = view
    case .billPayment:
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        view.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.addSubview(view)
        self.topView = view
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you code when the user taps a menu item? Will it use a Navigation Controller to push the `homeViewController`, or how is it implemented? Btw., what is the `"SliderController"`? I thought you meant `"HomeViewController"`, or am I getting it wrong?

Comment: @AndreasOetjen I have edited my question, you can find that code there. Also, the SliderController is the storyboard identifier for HomeViewController

Comment: I'm still not getting it. We are talking about the Home View Controller, but your code does not show it in the menuType switch/case statement. Secondly, looking at `case .promotion`, I don't get a clue how a individual promotion controller might be involved here. You are just replacing the `topView` with an empty `UIView`.